# matlab script node in Labview with different timing

Tags: matlab, timing, labview

I have a DAQ for Temperature measurment. I take a continuous sample rate and after DAQ, calculating temperature difference per minute (Cooling Rate: CR) during this process. This CR and temperature values are inserted into the Matlab script for a physical model running (predicting the temperature drop for next 30 sec). Then, I record and compare the predicted and experimental values in LabVIEW.

What i am trying to do is the matlab model is executing every 30 sec, and send out its predictions as an output from matlab script. One of this outputs helps me to change the Air Blower Motor Speed until next matlab run( eventually affect the temperature drop for next 30 sec as well, which becomes a closed loop). After 30 sec while main process is still running, sending CR and temperature values to matlab model again, and so on.

I have a case structure for this Matlab script. And inside of case structure i applied an elapsed time function to control the timing for the matlab script, but this is not working.

[image: Code example]

Comment: Please, show the code. Especially the part where you use the elapsed time functiuon with the case and the matlab script node

Comment: Here is the part where the elapsed time function is going to case structure and matlab script. [link](http://i.imgur.com/LtZvstb.jpg).

Comment: How exactly is the elapsed time function "not working". How does it behave differently from what you expect?

Comment: Let me try to explain:  When i eliminate  the elapsed time , the process is running as normal. I can monitor all data flow and calculations. Matlab is also running and getting data feed from the main process. (Elapsed time= 0, 0.1 are working fine) However, when i increase this time value to 15 sec or 30 sec. Then problems start to occur. The main process data flow is also getting slower and not responding as fast as before. And for the matlab script all the values are jumping to zero after lets say 15 sec running, then calculate again a output value, and then become zero again.

Comment: You realise that Tinitial and frozen_in will be overwritten every time? And there is no need for the locals of 'time init', Tinitial and frozen_in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. **Short answer**: I believe (one of) the reasons the program behaves weird on changed timing are **several race conditions** present in the code.

The part of the diagram presented shows several big problems with the code:

1. Local variables lead to race conditions. Use [dataflow](http://labviewwiki.org/Data_flow). E.g. you are writing to Tinitial local variable, and reading from Tinitial local varaible in the chunk of code with no data dependencies. It is not known whether reading or writing will happen first. It may not manifest itself badly with small delays, while big delays may be an issue. Solution: rewrite you program using the following example:

From Bad:

[image: Bad example]

To Good:

[image]

(nevermind broken wires)

2. Matlab script node executes in the main UI execution system. If it is executing for a long time, it may freeze indicators/controls as well as execution of other pieces of code. Change  execution system of other VIs in your program (say to "other 1") and see if the situation improves.